# SilverlightSpy alternative tool

Tags: silverlight

Can you suggest other tools similar to SilverlightSpy? I am just curious what alternatives exists out there.

What tool you use and why do you prefer it ?

Comment: IMHO, there's nothing coming even close to Silverlight Spy. There are a few projects which aren't really finished yet...

Like this one: http://www.reducingcomplexity.com/2010/01/is-anybody-interested-in-open-source.html

Answer (score 1):

I know of a tool that is fairly new but looks promising. It is invasive, unlike SilverlightSpy: you must add references and an attached property to make it work. It's really just a few references and you attach at the root, and you're good to go - easy to swap in/out. It shows a lot of promise for being able to visualize the graph and even exposes the data context properties. There is a trial available.

This is about the only tool I know that offers similar functionality. I only know of it because I met the owner of the company at a local user's group. I've used it in a few projects and it shows a lot of promise:

http://www.estringsoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

ANTS Memory Profiler http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

I tried both SilverlightSpy and ANTS but ANTS is better in my opinion. ANTS provides much more options and analysis, used it to solve a memory leak in a third party component. Also check out ANTS Performance Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I used symbiant in most of my silverlight work now - i'm a 'blender' so i just drop it in as a behavior to the root panel.  it has a good plugin model that's easy to author to and deep control over all your objects.  Free for non corp use.